# Trouble with a loop statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am having trouble writing the proper R code to perform a looped, if else, conditional test.  I am trying to solve for x (must be a whole number), such that `F_c = 5` (see below).  Both z and w are a series of known values, with z representing abundance values and w representing area sampled.  Right now I am essentially entering random values for x to see how close I can get to `F_c = 5`.  I would like to write a loop for this, and also have the loop stop when an iteration of x results in `F_c = 5`.  Any help would be very appreciated, I have spent a lot of time on this and haven't found a similar question posted yet (but if there is one please direct me to the solution).  Thanks,

```
cond = ifelse(z<=x, 1, 0)

F_c = 100*(sum(w*z*cond)/sum(w*z))
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of `w` and `z`? Is a solution guaranteed to exist? (This is not a job for a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much clear, but I'd assume you want to know at which point the cumulative sum of `w*z` reaches the five per cent of `sum(w*z)`, while following the order of `z`. If that's correct, you can try this:

```
 #for every z get the order indices
 indices<-order(z)
 #sort both z and w by z
 z<-z[indices]
 w<-w[indices]
 #now cumsum will give you the cumulative sum of a vector
 #and you compare it  to sum(z*w). 
 #findInterval will give you the index of when you reach .05
 res<-findInterval(.05,cumsum(w*z)/sum(w*z))
 #the value you are looking for:
 z[res]
```

Comment: The code that you provided worked perfectly, thank you!  I had approached this equation from the wrong perspective, I should have used the cumulative summary function rather than using the loop function to try a series of increasing values that would eventually provide the answer.